# Linq query to find specific image but fall back upon order if can't find it

Tags: c#, linq

**Question:**

I have the following:

```
[NotMapped]
public Image GetLargeSizeImage
{
    get
    {
            // pseudo code
            return this.ImageSet
                    .Where( x => x.ImageSizeType.Key == ImageSizeType.Large)
                    .IfNothingFoundThenOrderBy( x => x.ImageSizeType.Order)
                    .Where( x => x.ImageSizeType.Key != ImageSizeType.Original ) // Because we don't just want to go and get the original (largest size) if we can't find the Large size
                    .First();
    }
}

[NotMapped]
public Image GetMediumSizeImage 
{
    ...
```

> basically, I want to get the large image by calling my function... But
>   there is no large image for this particular thing... so i want it to
>   try the next best. It can do this by using the order column i gave it.

Something like this works but it has 2 database calls:

```
    public Image GetMediumSizeImage
    {
        get
        {
            Image image;

            try
            {
                image = this.ImageSet.Where( x => x.ImageSizeType.Key == ImageSizeType.Medium).First();                    
            }
            catch(Exception e )
            {
                image = this.ImageSet
                            .OrderBy( x => x.ImageSizeType.Order )
                            .Where( x => x.ImageSizeType.Key != ImageSizeType.Original )
                            .First();
            }

            return image;
        }
    }
```

**Extra notes**

---

[image]

```
public class ImageSizeType : ISoftDeletable, ITimeStamps, ICreatedBy
{
    ...

    // Order column is to degrade image with when selecting
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [NotMapped] private const string Prefix = "-";        
    [NotMapped] public const string Original = "original";
    [NotMapped] public const string ExtraLarge = "1024";
    [NotMapped] public const string Large = "800";
    [NotMapped] public const string Medium = "640";
    [NotMapped] public const string Small = "320";
    [NotMapped] public const string Thumbnail = "thumbnail";
    ...
}
```

[image]

**SOLVED**

```
public class BaseImage
{
    public virtual List<Image> ImageSet { get; set; }

    public Image GetImageBySize( string imageSizeTypeKey )
    {
        // If requesting original, we can just go get it
        if( imageSizeTypeKey == ImageSizeType.Original )
        {
            return this.ImageSet.Where( x => x.ImageSizeType.Key == imageSizeTypeKey ).First();
        }
        else
        {
            // This checks if image actually exists, if it doesn't it gets the next best one... Thumbnail wil always exist so it will always find one

            return this.ImageSet.Where( i => i.ImageSizeType.Key != ImageSizeType.Original )
            .OrderByDescending( i => i.ImageSizeType.Key == imageSizeTypeKey )
            .ThenBy(i => i.ImageSizeType.Order)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `ImageSizeType.Key == ImageSizeType.Original` mean by definition that its `Order == 1` or is the lowest possible `Order` value for an image?

Comment: The `OrderBy` appears to be pointless in this case. Your `Where` clause is not finding a match for whatever reason. I would put a breakpoint on there and double check the actual values. Could be as simple as a trailing space in the database or it just isn't filling into your object.

Comment: For each image, you only save one Original image, right? If so, why do you need to sort the result?

Comment: I added an image to explain what i'm after. It may be that my current code is throwing you off the scent.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are expecting (assuming Original) and what record you are actually getting?

Comment: Why don't you remove the Where condition, considering Original has the highest sort order of 1. It would then return either the Original, if present or the next highest size available based on the sort order

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Is "my large image" the Original?

Comment: I changed it a bit... hope that helps. basically, I want to get the large image by calling my function... But there is no large image for this particular thing... so i want it to try the next best. It can do this by using the order column i gave it.

Comment: Do you want to exclude the original from the result set? Please provide the expected output, in case the `Large` image is not present.

Comment: That code should throw an exception when there is no image with `ImageSizeType.Medium`, due to the call to `First()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method below gets the image of the given target size, returning the largest other (as defined by `Order`) if the target is not present, excluding the `Original`.

```
private Image GetMeTheImage(string targetSizeType) 
{
    return this.ImageSet
        .Where(i => i.ImageSizeType.Key != ImageSizeType.Original)
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.ImageSizeType.Key == targetSizeType)
        .ThenBy(i => i.ImageSizeType.Order)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}

public Image GetLargeSizeImage
{
    get
    {
        // Given OPs example table where Large is missing, 
        // this should return the ExtraLarge image.
        return GetMeTheImage(ImageSizeType.Large);

    }
}
```

Comment: Argh, not quite right.. Just realised! I've added a bit to bottom of OP... sorry to keep this going.

Comment: thing is, i don't want to order by key... I need to first check if the targetSizeType exists... if it does, return it... If it doesn't, order the types by Order column and return the first version it comes across... apart from original size

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 I have updated the answer with what I understand of your question. If this does not do what you expect, add an example of the expected output to your question.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 this orders by a match to the key, not the key value itself.

Comment: That's working now!! Thanks man! I'll show you my awesome class i made that i now extend... Thanks to your help... Really, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Will this not work? ofcourse this  will make 3 trips to the database.

```
    return this.ImageSet.OrderBy( x => x.ImageSizeType.Order )
           .Where( x => x.ImageSizeType.Key == ImageSizeType.Large )
           .FirstOrDefault()
        ?? this.ImageSet.OrderBy( x => x.ImageSizeType.Order )
           .Where( x => x.ImageSizeType.Key == ImageSizeType.Medium )
           .FirstOrDefault()
        ?? this.ImageSet.OrderBy( x => x.ImageSizeType.Order )
           .Where( x => x.ImageSizeType.Key == ImageSizeType.Small )
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or simply if `ImageSizeType.Order` will end up sorted where L = 3, M = 2, S = 1.

```
return this.ImageSet.OrderByDescending( x => x.ImageSizeType.Order )
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If we can come up with a solution that doesn't make 3 visits that'd be very handy.. Considering I am showing up to 100 items on 1 page... so that's 300 queries (in your example)... As for the ordering, I actually need to specify which image i use on which view, i actually have many other functions... working the same way. thank you for the try though, Atleast i have a solution if we can't find a better way!

Answer (score 0):

If you have other helper properties (these should be methods since you named them verbs) you could chain them together.

```
[NotMapped]
public Image GetLargeSizeImage
{
    get
    {
        return this
               .ImageSet.OrderBy( x => x.ImageSizeType.Order )
               .Where( x => x.ImageSizeType.Key == ImageSizeType.Large )
               .FirstOrDefault() ?? GetMediumSizeImage;
        }
    }
}

[NotMapped]
public Image GetMediumSizeImage
{
    get
    {
        return this
               .ImageSet.OrderBy( x => x.ImageSizeType.Order )
               .Where( x => x.ImageSizeType.Key == ImageSizeType.Medium)
               .FirstOrDefault() ?? GetSmallSizeImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice but, is there really no way of doing this with 1 db query?

Comment: I guess it would have to make the query to find out if one is true, so probs not cached. Thanks for your ongoing help man!

Answer (score 0):

You can create Priority list and join with ImageSet:

PriorityList Like:

```
var priorityImages = new List<string>(){ ImageSizeType.Large, ImageSizeType.Medium };
var orderList =   priorityImages.Select(y => new { Key = y, Order = priorityImages.IndexOf(y) }).ToList();
```

Then join with ImageSet:

```
private Image GetAppropriatedImage() 
{
    return this.ImageSet
      .Join(orderList, x => x.ImageSizeType.Key, y => y.Key,
                (x, y) => new { Image =x, Order = y.Order })
      .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
      .Select(x => x.Image) 
      .FirstOrDefault();
}
```